# Access different tables using the same type of object (NHibernate, C#)

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I've been having some problems dealing with NHibernate. I was able to solve most of them searching on the internet (mostly on StackOverflow) but this one I just couldn't solve.

I have two different tables in a database created from the same class.

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int Age { get; set; }
}
```

The tables names are, respectively, "Person" and "TestTable". But when I want to add something to "TestTable", and use the code below, it still adds what I want to add in the "Person" table. 
Anyone knows how to fix this?

```
    public bool Add( string entity_name, T product )
    {
        using ( ITransaction transaction = Session.BeginTransaction() )
        {
            Session.Save( entity_name, product );
            transaction.Commit();
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You may want to show how you are configuring your mappings for the two different tables.

Comment: Maybe you should read about one-to-one mapping.

Comment: Lukazoid, here's the thing: I want to use the same mapping to dynamically create new tables (with different names) and then be able to access them.

But I already found a Workaround. If you guys are interested on how I did it, just ask.

Comment: Mappings are static. It is possible to use the entityname to have the same class persisted to different tables but every new table needs to have the sessionfactory rebuild. If you found a way around it i'm interested to see it

Comment: Well, I was already creating one session per table retrieved, so that wasn't that big of a deal. When I get home I'll update the question with my workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, guys, so I had to delay a bit the response I promised because it just wouldn't work right. After one more entire day of working on it, now I have something interesting to share with you.

To be more precise, my problem, exactly, was: I have a system that accesses a database, and in my database I want to have:
- Static tables
- Dynamic tables.

Why would I want to have dynamic tables? I can give you guys an example: If I want to keep a log of what every person is doing in my app, and I want to do it in a way that even if LOTS of logs are in my database it doesn't end up being scalable (lots of conditionals in queries, lots of data to filter in one table), I have to have **one table per user log**.

Static tables would be the other ones, like the class I described you above.

In NHibernate there is not an easy way to do that. They want to map one class and one mapping into one table, and thats pretty much it. If you want to do anything else, then you have to **fool** the library. And that's pretty much what I ended up doing:

In one Library project, I created one static table like this:

```
  public class GenericTableInfo
    {
        public virtual string name { get; set; }
        public virtual int id { get; set; }
    }
```

At the same Library project, one class (and the xml, but I will not add the XML to this project) of my dynamic tables, just like this:

```
    public class DynamicPeople
{
        public virtual int id { get; set; }
        public virtual string log { get; set; }
}
```

When I generate my queries to be executed for the first time, using the assembly of the library I described you just above, NHibernate will create the static tables (the ones with XML and Class) and will not create a table related to my DynamicPeople class.

In a service, called AddTable(), I'll have to do the following:
- 1. Add the table name (its entity-name, to be more precise) in GenericTableInfo;

- 2. Get all the names contained in my GenericTableInfo (so, all of the Dynamic Tables I've created in my database);
- 3. Create a session like this:

  public static ISession AddTable( string TableName, List TableNames, Databases db )
  {

  ```
  if ( !SessionFactories.ContainsKey( db ) )
  {
      SessionFactories.Add( db, null );
  }
  var _cfg = new Configuration();
  _cfg.Configure( System.IO.Path.Combine( DatabaseConfigurationFiles[db] ) );
  // Add table to the database
  File.Move( @"C:\Generic.hbm.xml", @"C:\" + TableName + ".hbm.xml" );
  string aux = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\" + TableName + ".hbm.xml");
  aux = aux.Replace("generic", TableName);
  File.WriteAllText( @"C:\" + TableName + ".hbm.xml", aux );
  _cfg.AddFile(@"C:\" + TableName + ".hbm.xml");
  var update = new SchemaUpdate( _cfg );
  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  TextWriter output = new StringWriter( sb );
  update.Execute( true, true );
  aux = aux.Replace( TableName, "generic" );
  File.WriteAllText( @"C:\" + TableName + ".hbm.xml", aux );
  File.Move( @"C:\" + TableName + ".hbm.xml", @"C:\Generic.hbm.xml" );
  // Add dynamic tables to my mappings list.
  if ( SessionFactories[ db ] == null )
  {
      var configuration = new Configuration();
      configuration.Configure( DatabaseConfigurationFiles[ db ] );
      configuration.AddAssembly( Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() );
      string filename = @"C:\Generic.hbm.xml";
      string entityname = "generic";
      string a = "";
      for ( int i = 0 ; i < TableNames.Count() ; i++ )
      {
          File.Move( filename, @"C:\" + TableNames[ i ] + ".hbm.xml" );

          filename = @"C:\" + TableNames[ i ] + ".hbm.xml";
          a = File.ReadAllText( filename );

          a = a.Replace( entityname, TableNames[ i ] );
          entityname = TableNames[ i ];
          File.WriteAllText( filename, a );
          configuration.AddFile( filename );
          configuration.ClassMappings.Last().EntityName = entityname;
          configuration.ClassMappings.Last().Table.Name = entityname;
          configuration.ClassMappings.Last().DiscriminatorValue = entityname;
      }
      File.Move( filename, @"C:\Generic.hbm.xml" );
      filename = @"C:\Generic.hbm.xml";
      a = File.ReadAllText( filename );
      entityname = TableNames.Last();
      a = a.Replace( entityname, "generic" );
      File.WriteAllText( filename, a );

      SessionFactories[ db ] = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();                
  }
  else
  {
      DBStub.CloseSession( db );
      return DBStub.OpenSession( db, TableNames );
  }
  return SessionFactories[ db ].OpenSession();
  ```

  }

(Sorry about the first and last lines not being identified as code, I'm a noob at StackOverflow and it just didn't want to recognize those lines as code. :()

Modifying my Configuration adding my mappings manually by changing my xml entity-name and my mapping entity-name and tablename is going to fool the library so it doesn't know it's the same xml and, consequently, not the same mapping.

This way, you can find your tables when using NHibernates functions to query them, using its entity-name as key. They will all, then, be able to be mapped to the same class (In this example, they'll all be mapped into DynamicPeople).

I didn't see anyone else succeeding in trying this, so here's my 2 cents to the community, for today. If anyone have any questions, please don't hesitate asking. :)